# How to extract string between Nth and Mth occurrences of a pattern?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file path.txt with the path to a file(say a txt file):

```
/Folder/F1/F2/F3/F4/.../Fn/abc.txt
```

I want to extract the path i.e the string from beginning to the last occurrence of `/` (since the number of folder in path may vary).

I want to get:

```
/Folder/F1/F2/F3/F4/.../Fn
```

Which would be the best choice: sed/awk/perl/vi and how?

Answer (score 2):

`basename` and `dirname` print the last and all-but-last parts of a filename given as argument, so:

```
$ dirname "/Folder/F1/F2/F3/F4/.../Fn/abc.txt" 
/Folder/F1/F2/F3/F4/.../Fn
```

(or from a file: `dirname "$(< pathname.txt)"`  )

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use one of those tools you mentioned, you can do it with `sed`:

```
echo "/Folder/F1/F2/F3/F4/.../Fn/abc.txt" | sed "s/\/[^/]*$//"
sed -i "s/\/[^/]*$//" path.txt
```

If you are in bash, you can use Bash parameter expansion for this:

```
path=$(cat path.txt)
echo "${path%/*}"
```

And as mentioned by *ikkachu* you can use `dirname`.